# how to setup Docker for Rider in Linux

Tags: docker, rider, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Ubuntu 20.4. and installed Docker by following the steps from the docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository .

I installed Rider from Jetbrains Toolbox and want to setup Docker for my project. The Docker plugin is installed by default. I made sure that Docker is running via `systemctl status docker`.

I followed this guide on how to setup Docker for Rider https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/07/18/debugging-asp-net-core-apps-local-docker-container/ but unfortunately I get this error

> Cannot connect:
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
>   refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:2375 caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

[image]

What is missing or wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that dialog, check "Unix socket".

This will contact the Docker daemon via the special file `/var/run/docker.sock`.  You may need to adjust your user's permissions (typically by making yourself a member of the `docker` group) to get access to that file.

The "TCP socket" option is for an unusual and hard-to-securely-configure mode of connecting to Docker.  (Anyone who can run any `docker` command can run a container as root, and bind-mount any file from the host; you really don't want to make this level of access network-accessible.)  You shouldn't ever need the TCP socket mode..